# create calendar with seven following day

Tags: php

I want to draw a perpetual calendar on 7 following day

```
$dt = new DateTime;
if (isset($_POST['annee']) && isset($_POST['semaine'])) {
    $dt->setISODate($_POST['annee'], $_POST['semaine']);
} else {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
};
$annee= $dt->format('o');
$semaine= $dt->format('W');

$KlendrierPerpetuel="";
$KlendrierPerpetuel.='<table><tr>';
do {
    $KlendrierPerpetuel.='<td>'.$dt->format('D').'</td>';
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($semaine == $dt->format('W'));
$KlendrierPerpetuel.='</tr></table>';
echo $KlendrierPerpetuel;
```

it creates a table width day of the week instead of 7 next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it's actually a lot more simple...

```
$format = "y/m/d";
$date_arr = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i ++){
    if($i = 0)
        $date_arr[] = date($format);
    else
        $date_arr[] = date($format, strtotime("+$i day");
}
```

`strtotime` can parse date from a string like "+1 day" or "+1 week", so have the next day is quite simple. So you just need to loop the process and it's done.

PS : In your initial post, you seem to get some post parameters, you just need to put them in a `strtotime()` in the if.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for isn't completely clear, but I took my best guess and added user controls to implement it. You should be able to modify this to suit your needs:

```
<html>

<form method='post'>
    <input type='numeric' name='year' value='<?= $_POST['year'] ?: date('Y') ?>'>
    <input type='numeric' name='week' value='<?= $_POST['week'] ?: date('W') ?>'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<?php

$dt = new DateTime;
if (isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['week'])) {
    $dt->setISODate($_POST['year'], $_POST['week']);
} else {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
};
$year= $dt->format('o');
$week= $dt->format('W');

$KlendrierPerpetuel="";
$KlendrierPerpetuel.='<table><tr><td>'.$dt->format('M').'</td>';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
do {
    $KlendrierPerpetuel.='<td>'.$dt->format('d').'<br>'.$dt->format('D').'</td>';
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
$KlendrierPerpetuel.='<td>'.$dt->format('M').'</td></tr></table>';
echo $KlendrierPerpetuel;
```

This allows user specification of the year and week number, and displays the days of that week.

Comment: thx for your answer, i need to display the next days from today not just the current week